# Twitter like web app for MOSS 2007

Tags: twitter

Has anyone created a twitter like app in Sharepoint 2007? Would really like to know about your ideas and suggestions.

Comment: How would you want it implemented?  Web Part/JQuery/Page layout.  There are so many ways to do this, none of them are specific to SharePoint.  I guess the solution depends on the level of access you have to the farm.

Comment: Thanks Charles for a quick reply. 
The client I am working with already has a SharePoint 2007 site and they want to make use of it. 

So they I have planned it so far is that we will have a central tweet page which will display all the tweets and depending on subscription the user will only see the relevant ones. Does that make sense? I havent yet decided whether I want to do it with Web Parts or Page Layout as yet. Probably Web Parts for a quick turn around.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few options for you.

Michael Gannotti has this point on how to do it simply with a content editor web part and some javascript:
http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/mikeg/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=1202

Aidan Garnish has a solution here:
http://aidangarnish.net/blog/post/2009/02/Twitter-SharePoint-web-part.aspx

There's a CodePlex project called SharePointTwitter here:
http://sharepointtwitter.codeplex.com/

And if you just want to search twitter there's a web part here:
http://www.mattjimison.com/blog/2009/03/04/twitter-search-webpart/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [Team Status](http://community.zevenseas.com/Blogs/Daniel/archive/2009/05/09/release-version-of-our-%e2%80%9cassembly-free%e2%80%9d-team-status-template.aspx) solution from Zevenseas.

Comment: Thanks Wictor. This looks good. I will download it and have a go.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Yammer for SharePoint](http://blog.yammer.com/blog/2010/06/yammer-introduces-microsoft-sharepoint-2007-integration.html).

Answer (score 1):

Check this 
http://tweetpart.codeplex.com/